# converting array to another array

Tags: php

hello friends I have this array

```
    Array
(
    [fieldset_name] => Personal Details
    [field_name] => applicant_name
    [field_label] => Your Name
    [field_type] => text
    [css_classes] => required
    [minlength] => 4
    [maxlength] => 10
    [default_value] => 
    [help_text] => 
)
Array
(
    [fieldset_name] => Personal Details
    [field_name] => applicant_address
    [field_label] => Address
    [field_type] => textarea
    [css_classes] => required
    [minlength] => 4
    [maxlength] => 10
    [default_value] => 
    [help_text] => 
)
```

and I want the result should be as

```
Array(
 "Personal Details" => array(
   array(
     'fieldset_name' => "Personal Details"
     field_name => applicant_name
     field_label => Your Name
   ),
   array(
     'fieldset_name' => "Personal Details"
     field_name => applicant_address
     field_label => Address
   ),

 )
)
```

So how to do this

Comment: i have a serious doubts your second array declaration code is compilable

Comment: What, besides the `fieldset_name` ("Personal Details") comes from the original array?

Comment: please paste your exact array in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and also the desired array

Comment: @diEcho The OP should post code *here*, not somewhere else. What's wrong with SO's code handling?

Comment: To be able to convert from one array to the other the information needs to be in the first array.  From your questions I cannot see any information related to address or city.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after (untested):

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach( $originalArray as $value )
{
    $key = $value[ 'fieldset_name' ];
    if( !isset( $resultArray[ $key ] ) )
    {
        $resultArray[ $key ] = array();
    }

    $resultArray[ $key ][] = array(
        'fieldset_name' => $key,
        'field_name' => $value[ 'field_name' ],
        'field_label' => $value[ 'field_label' ]
    );
}

var_dump( $resultArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets see we have two arrays and what you want is push those two into one..

```
   $a= array(
   [fieldset_name] => Personal Details
   [field_name] => applicant_name
   [field_label] => Your Name
   [field_type] => text
   [css_classes] => required
   [minlength] => 4
   [maxlength] => 10
   [default_value] => 
   [help_text] => 
);

   $b=array(
[fieldset_name] => Personal Details
[field_name] => applicant_address
[field_label] => Address
[field_type] => textarea
[css_classes] => required
[minlength] => 4
[maxlength] => 10
[default_value] => 
[help_text] => 
);

$c=array();
$c[]=$a;
$c[]=$b;
```

$c is the array which is required

Answer (score 0):

**Just Try With The Following :**

***PHP Part :***

```
<?php
$array_name = array('fieldset_name'=>'Personal Details',
          'field_name'=>'applicant_name',
          'field_label'=>'Your Name',
          'field_type'=>'text',
          'css_classes'=>'required',
          'minlength'=>'4',
          'maxlength'=>'10',
          'default_value'=>'',
          'help_text'=>'');

$array_address = array('fieldset_name'=>'Personal Details',
          'field_name'=>'applicant_address',
          'field_label'=>'Address',
          'field_type'=>'textarea',
          'css_classes'=>'required',
          'minlength'=>'4',
          'maxlength'=>'10',
          'default_value'=>'',
          'help_text'=>'');

$array_personal_details = array('Personal Details'=> array($array_name,$array_address));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_personal_details);          
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.